# Android, Realm, Gradle: Error:Annotation processor: RealmProcessor not found

Tags: android, gradle, realm

Android Studio 2.3.3

My project bulid.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/anko' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

My app build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.project.com"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 53
        versionName "1.1.13"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["resourcePackageName": android.defaultConfig.applicationId]
            }
        }
    }

    // exclude buildTypes = "debug" from build Variants
    variantFilter { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals('debug')) {
            variant.setIgnore(true);
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        def APP_NAME_STAGE = "My project Stage"
        def APP_ID_SUFFIX_STAGE = ".stage"

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        stage {
            initWith(debug)
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

def AAVersion = '4.3.0'

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.11.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.2.5'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
    compile 'us.feras.mdv:markdownview:1.1.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:0.9.1'
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And project bulid and run success.
So now I want to add Realm. I add in build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

And as result I get error.

Error:Annotation processor '__gen.AnnotationProcessorWrapper_stage_io_realm_processor_RealmProcessor' not found
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileStageJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>       :app:compileDevJavaWithJavac
>       Destination for generated sources was modified by kapt. Previous value = myProject\app\build\generated\source\apt\dev
>       error: Annotation processor             '__gen.AnnotationProcessorWrapper_dev_io_realm_processor_RealmProcessor' not found

Comment: please look [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. Two approach:

1. By **apt** plugin

in app's budile.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

apt {
    arguments {

        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId

        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
    }

}

dependencies {
apt 'io.realm:realm-android-library:3.5.0'
apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
}
```

OR

2. By **kapt** plugin

   ```
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

   kapt {

       arguments {

           arg( "resourcePackageName", android.defaultConfig.applicationId)

           arg( "androidManifestFile", 

           variant.outputs[0]?.processResourcesTask?.manifestFile)

       }

   }
   ```

   dependencies {

   ```
   kapt 'io.realm:realm-android-library:3.5.0'

   kapt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kotlin, then you'll need to use KAPT.

```
annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
```

should be

```
kapt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

should be

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

and

```
 //       javaCompileOptions {
 //           annotationProcessorOptions {
 //               arguments = ["resourcePackageName": android.defaultConfig.applicationId]
 //           }
 //       }

kapt {
    arguments {
        arg('resourcePackageName', android.defaultConfig.applicationId)
    }
}
```

EDIT: based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/34708575/2413303

```
kapt {
    arguments {
        arg('androidManifestFile', variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile)
        arg('resourcePackageName', android.defaultConfig.applicationId)
    }
}
```

If that still doesn't work, then the question becomes AndroidAnnotations related.

Comment: `Error:(54, 0) No such property: processResources for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApkVariantOutputData`

Comment: what is your [kotlin version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44043185/2413303)? this new error seems to be [very similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44170064/2413303)

Comment: ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2', classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

Comment: Are you using Android Studio 2.3.x or 3.0.0-x?

Comment: Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: After add: "apply plugin: **com.neenbedankt.android-apt**, I get another error: `Error:error: Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file, using  generation folder [myproject\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stage])`

Comment: you're not supposed to apply that if you're using KAPT.

Comment: I found solutions. See bellow (in my post)