# Android, Gradle, Realm, Kotlin: Error:error: Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, gradle, annotations, kotlin

Android Studio 2.3.3, Java 8, Kotlin 1.1.3-2

Project's build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/anko' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

App's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 53
        versionName "1.17.53"

        apt {
            arguments {
                arg('androidManifestFile', variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile)
                arg('resourcePackageName', android.defaultConfig.applicationId)
            }
        }
    }

    // exclude buildTypes = "debug" from build Variants
    variantFilter { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals('debug')) {
            variant.setIgnore(true);
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        def APP_NAME_STAGE = "My Project Stage"
        def APP_ID_SUFFIX_STAGE = ".stage"

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        stage {
            initWith(debug)
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

def AAVersion = '4.3.0'

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.11.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.2.5'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
    compile 'us.feras.mdv:markdownview:1.1.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':module_1')
    compile project(':module_2')
    compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:0.9.1'
    kapt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

But when I try to build proejct, I get error:

```
Error:error: Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file, using  generation folder [myproject\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stage])

 java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:144)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:397)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:798)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:825)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:797)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:865)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:791)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:364)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:865)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:354)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:139)
```

Comment: can you put the directory structure of your project?

Comment: _project\app\src, project\module_1\src_

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documenation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html)...

> If you previously used the android-apt plugin, remove it from your build.gradle file and replace usages of the apt configuration with kapt. If your project contains Java classes, kapt will also take care of them.

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but I do see that you are using `apt` in your gradle script.  Give it a shot.

Comment: Not help. in kapt section: `Error:(48, 0) No such property: processResources for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApkVariantOutputData`

Comment: I found solution. See here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675247/android-realm-gradle-errorannotation-processor-realmprocessor-not-found/45675558?noredirect=1#comment78321394_45675558)